# What kind of synchronization does this code need?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a threaded server application that stores `List<Item> dataList`. There is a single writing thread that modifies, adds and removes items from the list, and multiple threads that read from this list.

What kind of synchronization is required to ensure the writes happen in order as they were called and provide maximum performance for the reads i.e. if a write is busy reads must just provide the previous value before the read.

I currently use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` for it's separate Read and Write locking capabilities, but it feels as though there is a lot of expensive overhead calling the ReadLocks that is unnecessary since all I want is for writes to be guaranteed in order?

As far as I understand reading reference types and value types should provide atomic access so locking is perhaps not necessary?

Performance is a big concern and it seems like optimization of my synchronization structure could improve by quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a producer/consumer pattern.  In .Net 4, there is the [ConcurrentQueue<T> class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265) in the `System.Threading.Concurrent` namespace.  You are only synchronising when adding and removing from queue.

Answer (score 0):

Without synchronization, there is a chance that a read will get partial information from before and after the write operation (for ex: 30% from the old list and 70% from the new list). 
If this is not an issue, then you are not required to use any synchronization as long as there is one single writer.

If your list contains objects, you might prefer writing your new data into a new object then swap this new element with the inlist one. 
Changing a reference should be atomic unless there are some internal mechanics I don't know about.

```
Object temp = new Object();
temp.value = 5;
temp.name = "whatever";
list[5] = temp;
```

instead of:

```
list[5].value = 5;
list[5].name = "whatever";
```

Comment: Accessing the item properties via direct approach isn't different than using an indirect pointer. It's the same thing, the producer thread can still change the item's properties.

Answer (score -1):

`ReaderWriterLockSlim`  isn't really needed here, unless there is a chance you cannot enter the lock for some significant reason.
A Simple `Lock(syncObj)` would suffice, just place locks before read/write operations.

If `TryEnter` is needed, we need to see your code.

Comment: This would not be ideal as far as I understand locks as then essentially only one thread can then read at a time, since we are locking both on reads and writes on the same object.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and ReaderWriterLockSlim will give you a good solution here. Concurrent Queue isn't good enough, cause 1. you're not using a queue, 2. if you change an item, your consumers might access invalid data.